# adding a sanskrit keyboard using the setxkbmap command in terminal?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus

I'm trying to find an efficient way to type the correct roman transliteration of Sanskrit characters. This is done using a special keyboard that allows one to type diacritic marks in unicode. Standard diacritic marks for Sanskrit are available in unicode. I can type this very efficiently on OSX on my Macintosh with no problems, using a keyboard called "Easy Unicode" created by  Toshiya Unebe.  There have been attempts made to mimic this for linux, as for example at https://garudam.info/sanskrit-transliteration-keyboard-on-linux/, but I have found that this code doesn't work. There is an IAST unicode keyboard available for use with Ibus, but it's quite buggy and seems to cause conflicts. I've tried a number of solutions over the years, looking for a good option. This is important to me since I am responsible for editing and translating books in Sanskrit and Bengali. There are keyboard options available for natively inputting these languages, but I have always found the best option inputting in Roman transliteration as above-mentioned. I want to be able to switch back and forth between an English and Romanized Sanskrit transliteration keyboard.  I've also tried FCITx and different m17n but it seems to crash and/or create conflicts with Ibus. Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this code: I didn't test it yet, https://github.com/bdhrs/pali-sanksrit-keyboard-for-linux just looking for an IAST layout as well.